# SSH "Framework" to write programs that will keep a connection open and feed commands to the servers

Tags: scripting, ssh

I am looking for some kind of framework that will allow me to do connect to multiple servers using SSH and keep the connection open, reopen it if it dies, and allow me to run commands to it and report back. For example, check disk space on all the machines right away, so I'd do `results = object.run("df -h")` and it returns an array with the response from all the machines (I am not looking for a monitoring system).

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I would use Python and the [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html) framework. Lets you easily execute commands on a set of servers - [like doing deployment](http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/using-fabric-for-deployment/)

with Fabric you could do

```
from fabric import run, env
def getSpace(server):
   env.host_string
   run("df -h")

>>> fab getSpace("234.24.32.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use Python and the [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) library. Writing the functionality that runs a given command on a specified set of servers is then a simple matter of programming.